# How to store environment variable in dockerfile or docker compose.yaml whose value is fetched from the os on which it gets deployed?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to use some env variables in my app, that runs on docker container. How can I get those environment variables in my code?

If I use dockerfile or docker-compose yaml, then how can I export it to read the values from the os on which it runs eventually and how can it be read in the code?

So for example, if I run my docker on AWS instances, I need the AWS keys from the instance to be used in my containerized app.

Comment: create a `.env` file and access the desired variables in docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: Note that if you're using one of the standard AWS SDKs, and your instance has an IAM role bound to it, you can get credentials through the EC2 metadata service without setting any environment variables (even if you're running in a container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For docker-compose:

Create a `.env` file in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`

For example, for .env file with contents:

```
DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME=docker_image_here
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=POSTGRES_PASSWORD_HERE
```

You may then access the variables inside the docker-compose.yml file:

```
service-name:
  web:
  image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
  environment:
    postgres_password: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
```